# My "then" code is inactivate in Flutter. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: flutter, dart

The main function of this code is that when Firestore upload porocess end, then change the page to HomePage.
But my ".then" code is inactivate.

[Code]

```
   await Firestore.instance.collection('post').add(
      {
        'contents': textEditingController.text,
        'displayName': widget.user.displayName,
        'email': widget.user.email,
        'photoUrl': downloadUrl,
        'userPhotoUrl': widget.user.photoUrl,
      });
} else {
  await Firestore.instance.collection('post').add({
    'contents': textEditingController.text,
    'displayName': widget.user.displayName,
    'email': widget.user.email,
    'photoUrl': 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/woonsancommunity2-c95f8.appspot.com/o/post%2FNo%20IMG.001.png?alt=media&token=47a39955-39a0-447f-8846-d89149f40ee3',
    'userPhotoUrl': widget.user.photoUrl,
  }).then(() {
    Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context) =>
        HomePage(widget.user)),
    );
  });
}
```

In this situation, .then code is inactivate.(Gray Font Color)..
Plase help me!

[image]

Comment: What is the error kindly mention the error in your question

Comment: .then((value) {...})

Comment: You don't need to use `await` and `.then` same time, just use `await` then next part navigate. Also, you might wanna check the state is mounted or not before push

Answer (score 0):

Since you await the process of adding to the collection, there is no point at all having the `then()` method called.

Just move out the Navigator push method from the `then()` method and remove the use of `then()`.

The callback in `then()` is used to be called when the previous Future is finished, but since you await the Future, you are guaranteed that the statements after will be called when the Future had been completed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're combining Promise/Future with asynchronous code.

If you put `await` before a Future, it will wait for it to resolve and then return error or result based on what it does.

To Fix your code, either use `await` like this.

```
const result = await ...; // remove then block
if(result){
    // Your then block code here
}
```

Or you can remove `await`

Answer (score 0):

first of all, its redundat to use `await` and `then` at the same function.

- `await`: is meant to interrupt the process flow until the async method has finished
- `then`: is not interrupt the process, but enables you to run code when the async is finished

**Read this for more explanation and demo: [await vs then in Flutter](https://medium.com/@pmatatias/await-vs-then-in-flutter-28c2ce600cea)**

---

the error in your code is, you are use `then` with wrong way.
this is it should be:

```
Future<R> then<R>(FutureOr<R> Function(String) onValue, {Function? onError})
```

### Solution:

```
 }).then((value) { // you miss the "value" 
    Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context) =>
        HomePage(widget.user)),
    );
  });
```